# Laravel: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251)

Tags: laravel

Have an ajax request in my page and give me an error

Route file:

```
Route::post('/record/store','RecordsController@store').
```

The `sortSBERCS` function return array data, the problem occur when this array data is big, if I call `dd()` before return array in this function it's show array, but when I call `dd()` after

```
$all_records = $this->sortSBERCS($record_data,$sensetive_date,$unique_id);
```

this row, it's return error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 251)`.

Store function:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    { 
        $record_data = $request->record_data; 
        $sensetive_date = $request->sensetive_date; 
        $unique_id= $request->unique_id; 
        $all_records = $this->sortSBERCS($record_data,$sensetive_date,$unique_id); 
        return json_encode($all_records); 
    }
```

Javascript :

```
data = {};
data = $('form').serialize();
data += "&unique_id="+unique_id;
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/record/store',
    data: data
});
```

Any help  will be appreciated

Comment: Please show your store function

Comment: public function store(Request $request){
 $record_data = $request->record_data;
 $sensetive_date = $request->sensetive_date;
 $unique_id= $request->unique_id;
 $all_records = $this->sortSBERCS($record_data,$sensetive_date,$unique_id);
 return json_encode($all_records);
}

Comment: What's in the `sortSBERCS` function?

Comment: Can you post your javascript where you are making the ajax request?

Comment: can you post the form view as well. Seems you have to use `$('.form').on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ....other stuffs });` I can be sure though until you post that form view. You can also post some other routes you think might be important

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `sortSBERCS()`, try [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortBy) this may your solution.